# MySQL NOT IN or NOT REGEXP

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: `voters`, `banned_domains`
I want to get all the votes except where banned domains
This query works well

```
SELECT * FROM `voters` email NOT REGEXP('tempmail.com|tempmail.org')
```

I want to compare with the request to another table, but this code does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM `voters` email NOT IN(SELECT domain FROM banned_domains)
```

Thanks a lot

**UPDATE**: I apologize for the incomplete data. 
In the `voters` I have a full email address
example 'oleole@mail.com' 
but in the `banned_domains` i have only domain names 
example 'mail.com'

I changed the query, but it does not work

```
SELECT * FROM  voters
WHERE DISTINCT RIGHT(  voters.email , LENGTH(  voters.email ) - LOCATE(  '@', voters.email ) ) NOT IN (SELECT domain FROM banned_domains)

ERROR:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT RIGHT(  voters.email , LENGTH(  voters.email ) - LOCATE(  '@', voters.e' at line 2
```

Comment: when you say "does not work", is it; a syntax error, wrong results, what? Also, looks like you're missing `WHERE`

Comment: `NOT IN` does an exact match, it doesn't do REGEXP matching.

Comment: Both queries are missing a `where` clause.  If the first works, I assume this is just a typographical error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to perform a `REGEXP` match between the email and domain, but `NOT IN` performs an exact match.

```
SELECT v.*
FROM voters AS v
LEFT JOIN banned_domains AS d ON v.email REGEXP d.domain
WHERE d.domain IS NULL
```

Comment: Dear Barmar, i traed exicute your query, but received error #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'regexp'

Comment: may be because they do not use a splitter '|'?

Comment: That's because you have different `collation` settings for the two tables. Search SO for the error message to find out how to resolve that.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `where` in your query change

```
SELECT * FROM `voters` email NOT IN(SELECT domain FROM banned_domains)
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM `voters` WHERE email NOT IN(SELECT domain FROM banned_domains)
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical reason for this would be that `domain` takes on `NULL` values.  You can fix this by explicitly filtering these out:

```
SELECT *
FROM `voters`
WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT domain FROM banned_domains WHERE domain is not null);
```

However, I prefer using `NOT EXISTS`, because the semantics are more what people expect:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM `voters` v
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM banned_domains bd WHERE bd.domain = v.domain);
```

NOTE:  I assume the issue is not the missing `where` clause, because you claim the first query works.

Comment: Why would a list of banned domains include null values in the domain column?

Comment: @Barmar . . . Perhaps because a domain was banned and then removed.  It's not my database, so I obviously don't know.  I doubt the problem is the `where` clause, because the OP claims the first version works.